# Excel office-js: Merge 2 or more cells

Tags: javascript, cell, office-js

I need to merge 2 cells and have a value in the merged cell.
My (failed) attempts:

## #1

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    const newSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("New sheet 1");
    newSheet.activate();
    const values = [
        ["Row 1", "", "Row 1"],
        ["Row 2", "Row 2", "Row 2"]
    ];
    newSheet.getRange("A1").values = values;
    newSheet.getRange("A1:B1").merge = true;
});
```

## #2

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    const newSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("New sheet 1");
    newSheet.activate();
    const values = [
        ["Row 1", "", "Row 1"],
        ["Row 2", "Row 2", "Row 2"]
    ];
    newSheet.getRange("A1").values = values;
    newSheet.getRange("A1").getResizedRange(0, 1).merge = true;
});
```

Where did I do wrong?

**EDIT**: The marked answer is correct not because its main content - but because [Kim Brandl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2781454/kim-brandl)'s later reply - in which,  my solution is using API 1.1 - but the `merge()` can only work in [API 1.2](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think that if you want to merge you have to set range.I.E (A1:A5)

Comment: As I said, those attempts failed, so I already tested the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that creates a new sheet, adds 2 rows of data to the sheet, and then merges cells A1 and B1.

```
Excel.run(function (context) {

    // create new sheet, add 2 rows of data
    const newSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("New sheet 1");
    newSheet.activate();
    const values = [
        ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 1"],
        ["Row 2", "Row 2", "Row 2"]
    ];
    newSheet.getRange("A1").getResizedRange(values.length - 1, values[0].length - 1).values = values;

    // merge cells A1 and B1 
    var myRange = newSheet.getRange("A1:B1");
    myRange.merge();

    return context.sync();
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

Here's the result of running this code in Excel:

[image: Excel data]

**Note the following:**

- If multiple cells within the range that you're merging contain values, then only the value in the first cell of the range (i.e., the upper-left-most cell in the range) is persisted -- all subsequent cell values are wiped-out. For example, the sheet in the example above initially contained a value in cell B1 ("Row 2") -- but as the screenshot above shows, this value is wiped-out whenever cell B1 is merged with cell A1.
- You only need a single `context.sync()` -- since you're just writing data to the sheet and merging cells, those commands can be queued up and executed with a single sync() at the end.
- It's important to always include error handling (as I've done with the `catch` statement), to ensure that things don't silently fail without you knowing it.

**Update (adding info about Requirement Sets)**:

One additional bit of info -- looks like `range.merge()` was added to the Excel JavaScript API as part of Requirement Set 1.2. I'd suggest you verify that you're running a version/platform of Office that supports Requirement Set 1.2 (or higher) -- https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.  For information about how to get the latest version of Office, see [this topic](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/install-latest-office-version) in the Office Add-ins docs.

Comment: I have no idea how you ran this with no errors. I still receive the same error

Comment: You can quickly and easily try this snippet yourself by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST ID: d21b543f91fdd82e745f871882f0cd84

Comment: One additional bit of info -- looks like range.merge() was added to the Excel JavaScript API as part of Requirement Set 1.2.  I'd suggest that you verify that you're running a version/platform of Office that supports Requirement Set 1.2 (or higher).  https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Wow. You are correct. How do I upgrade my solution to use API 1.2?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include info about Requirement Sets.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that [merge()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range#mergeacross-bool) is a method, not a property. For a simple merge of cells in a range like this, the syntax would be:

```js
var range = newSheet.getRange("A1:B1");
range.merge();
```

The second issue is that you need to `sync` after this in order to commit your changes to the worksheet:

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {
  const newSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("New sheet 1");
  newSheet.load('name');
  return context.sync().then(function () {                       
      var range = newSheet.getRange("A1:B1");
      range.merge();       
      newSheet.activate(); 
      return context.sync();
  });        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But, I tried: `newSheet.getRange("A1:B1").merge(true); returrn context.sync();`, but it didn't work. Even further - it threw an `InvalidArgument` exception.

Comment: Sorry, looks like a mistakenly pasted over part of my code. I've updated my answer with the corrected syntax. You need to `load` your page after you've created it and then do the merge. This code will add a new page, merge cells A1 and B1 and then activate that page.

Comment: 2 things: 1) For some reason, it doesn't work. It still throws an `InvalidArgument` exception. 2) FYI, I use pure JavaScript, not TypeScript.

Comment: Which lines gives you an exception?

Comment: The same line every time - `range.merge();`.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this running the snippet above. If you set a breakpoint there, is `range` populated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152471/discussion-between-avi12-and-marc-lafleur-msft).

Answer (score 0):

Try this from official [doc](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#examples-14)

```
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheetName = "New Sheet 1";
        var rangeAddress = "A1:B1"; 
        var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
        range.select();
        return ctx.sync(); 
    }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
    });
```